# How to specify a default screen for react native stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to navigate between two screens in my RN application: Daily and AllTodos. I want to make sure that when the navigator renders Daily by default. This is the code which I have used which accords the  [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#initialroutename) :

```
const StackNavigator = ({component}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Daily">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Daily"
          component={Daily}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="AllTodos"
          component={AllTodos}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

But still AllTodos page is rendered by default. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destructure the 'component' props. Take it off.

```
const StackNavigator = ({component}) // take off the component props => {
```

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: Show me your App.jsx or tsx file